# Word for one who likes to share knowledge when asked

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Working in an organization where your coworkers like to share information and knowledge.

What can we call someone who likes to share knowledge when asked?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? There is something like _know-it-all_, but that has a negative connotation, which I think might not be what you want.

Comment: A *walking encyclopedia* is a good term for someone who has a vast store of knowledge and is open to sharing.

Comment: A *Stack Exchanger*! :)

Comment: Thanks for answering, I mean if i can put 2 different situation: 1. When you ask someone about something and reply with a short answer. 2. Get your answer plus some additional information that you didn't ask for. So how would we describe the second one?

Answer (score 2):

**[forthcoming](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/forthcoming)** (ODO)

> **2.1** Willing to divulge information.
>   ‘Of course doctors and receptionists should be forthcoming with this information.’
>   ‘I immediately liked the fact that he was open and forthcoming.’

O'Neill, "User-Developer Cooperation in Software Development," [p.198](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=OjSrXcfNk3IC&pg=PA198&dq=%22very%20forthcoming%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKqKu6wO7bAhUOOisKHWhbAL04FBDoAQhTMAg#v=onepage&q=%22very%20forthcoming%22&f=false):

> Users were very forthcoming with information, proposals, requests and so on, freely using the shared external models to frame and …

Comment: I think forthcoming would be the answer but, would you agree that we could use the same word for someone who talks about irrelevant stuff after giving an answer?

Comment: @zi9o "who talks about irrelevant stuff" -- just discard the fluff and pick up the content, maybe. But where does that sense come from for the word *forthcoming*? I don't think it has any connotations of "going on and on" or digressing.

Answer (score -1):

I think someone who shares knowledge, when asked, is '**communicative**'.

> willing to talk to people and give them information:

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/communicative)

> tending to communicate : talkative

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/communicative)

> Election Commission needs to be more **communicative**

[The Quint - 30 May 2018](https://www.thequint.com/news/india/election-commission-needs-to-be-more-communicative-sy-quraishi)

> **Communicative Competence** in Business English

[B M H Robinson - publication](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=1g-jQBswSUMC&printsec=frontcover&dq=communicative&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjctLOQ2u7bAhXLIsAKHY2mBoQ4ChDoAQg7MAQ#v=onepage&q=communicative&f=false)